# SQL split eggs in two baskets - date alternation

Tags: sql, date, case, alternate

I have an interesting and specific problem. Specific, because I cannot explain it simply, but I think it should be reasonably easy to solve. With that said, I cannot find similar question, because I don’t know how to look for it!

In one table, among other columns, there is a date column, with same multiple entries repeating for a year or so in a specific pattern.

For example:

**TermDate**

- 2013/07/16
- 2013/07/16
- 2013/07/16
- 2013/07/23
- 2013/07/23
- 2013/07/23
- 2013/07/23
- 2013/07/30
- 2013/07/30
- 2013/07/30
- 2013/07/30
  …

(Every Tuesday)

I need to change those dates to Mondays and Wednesdays, so that  **‘2013/07/16’** would become ‘2013/07/15’, **‘2013/07/23’** would then be ‘‘2013/07/17’’, and **‘2013/07/30’** would be next first available Monday – ‘2013/07/22’, etc.

Do you see what I mean? Obviously I would need CASE statement for this, but does anyone have an idea how exactly to write it?

Thanks!

I am using the MS SQL SERVER by the way!

Comment: Are you asking for a translation that rounds the dates *down* to the previous Monday or Wednesday, whichever occurs soonest?  `Monday => stay same.  Tues => Monday.  Weds => Stay same.  Thurs-Sunday => Wednesday.`?  And so all three entries on 16th June ALL become 15th July?   ***(Also, is this MySQL, MS SQL Server, SQLite, etc?)***

Comment: Or, maybe not.  You want to take all records with the first date, and round them down to the preceding Monday or Wednesday (which becomes a *base date* for subsequent calculations).  The next group of records with the same date then map to the Monday or Wednesday immediately after the *base date*?  And the next group or records with the same date map to the second Monday or Wednesday immediately after the *base date*?

Comment: You got it right this time! I'm using MS SQL, sorry, I forgot to add that info!

Comment: are you always moving to `next first [Monday] or [Wednesday]`?

Comment: Yes, basically those are some kind of schedules, and now I need to change them to use every available Monday/Wednesday, instead of Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL to round a date down to the start of the week...

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, <theDate>), 0)

NOTE: This is NOT affected by your DATEFIRST environment setting.
```

SQL to conditionally round it down to a Monday or Wednesday...

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, <theDate>) IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7) THEN
  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, <theDate>), 0)
ELSE
  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, <theDate>), 0) + 2
END

NOTE : DATEPART() _IS_ affected by your DATEFIRST environment setting.
       This code has assumed SET DATEFIRST 7
```

Then you can put all of your records into a sequence.  If it's position 1 you add two days to the base date (Monday => Wednesday), if it's position 2 you add seven days (Monday => Next Monday), position three adds nine days, etc.

This simplifies down to `(position / 2) * 7 + (position % 2) * 2`...

```
position : (position / 2) * 7 + (position % 2) * 2
--------------------------------------------------
       0 : 0
       1 : 2
       2 : 7
       3 : 9
       4 : 14
       5 : 16
       6 : 21
```

With a note that if your *base date* happens to be a Wednesday, you need to treat all of your other dates as having a position one higher...

So, I'd do this...

```
SELECT
  term_lookup.TermDate,
  base_lookup.base_date
  + ((term_lookup.term_id + base_lookup.base_id) / 2) * 7
  + ((term_lookup.term_id + base_lookup.base_id) % 2) * 2   AS new_date
FROM
(
  SELECT
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, MIN(TermDate)), 0)                  AS base_date,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, MIN(TermDate)) IN (1, 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   AS base_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS base_lookup
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT
    TermDate,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TermDate) - 1   AS term_id
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    TermDate
)
  AS term_lookup
```

If that gives you the right results, join them back on to your data to do the update.

Comment: I'll will thank you immediately, and check whether it works later!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE Table1
SET TermDate = DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATEPART(weekday, TermDate ) 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 1
                        WHEN 2 THEN 0
                        WHEN 3 THEN 1
                        WHEN 4 THEN 0
                        WHEN 5 THEN 4
                        WHEN 6 THEN 3
                        WHEN 7 THEN 2
                     END, TermDate )
```

Comment: Seriously?  Did you read any of the comments?  Where I've already asked if this is what the OP meant, and the OP said he means something else...

Comment: @MatBailie - I didn't see your question. now I see that I missed the point